# WiFi does not work

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros

Just installed ubuntu and my wifi does not work.

I ran [the script you have](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and this is the output I got. 
I have no idea what I should do now..

I know I have atheros AR2413/AR2414. 
I think I have ath5k. 
no idea what these mean.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 Sep 2014 00:26 IDT +0300

Booted last: 29 Sep 2014 00:24 IDT +0300

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:45 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7592]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

04:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg] [168c:001a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Compex Wireless 802.11 b/g  MiniPCI Adapter, Rev A1 [WLM54G] [168c:2052]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:0750 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

mxm_wmi                12893  1 nouveau
wmi                    18673  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
ath5k                 134977  0 
ath                    23922  1 ath5k
mac80211              546051  1 ath5k
cfg80211              409394  3 ath,ath5k,mac80211

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:85.64.169.225  Bcast:85.64.169.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4261:86ff:fe0b:6d36/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1045 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:845 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1034991 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:101735 (101.7 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         85.64.169.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
85.64.169.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         85.64.169.225
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         85.64.169.1

    DNS:             212.143.0.1
    DNS:             212.143.212.143

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Jerusalem (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath5k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/ath5k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for 5xxx series of Atheros 802.11 wireless LAN cards.
author:         Nick Kossifidis
author:         Jiri Slaby
srcversion:     F36818A2F0BCB2B0CC9BB8C
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        FF:9A:DA:11:B8:55:51:6A:72:98:65:9D:4E:3F:BB:76:C5:4A:D3:30
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)
parm:           fastchanswitch:Enable fast channel switching for AR2413/AR5413 radios. (bool)
parm:           no_hw_rfkill_switch:Ignore the GPIO RFKill switch state (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     88A67C5359B02C5A710AFCF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        FF:9A:DA:11:B8:55:51:6A:72:98:65:9D:4E:3F:BB:76:C5:4A:D3:30
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     B822641624778B987844F6F
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        FF:9A:DA:11:B8:55:51:6A:72:98:65:9D:4E:3F:BB:76:C5:4A:D3:30
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C2478077E22138832B71659
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        FF:9A:DA:11:B8:55:51:6A:72:98:65:9D:4E:3F:BB:76:C5:4A:D3:30
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath5k]
fastchanswitch: N
nohwcrypt: Y
no_hw_rfkill_switch: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf]
options ath5k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

After A LOT MORE digging - found something in my dmesg

```
ath5k 0000:04:01.0: registered as 'phy0'
ath5k: phy0: POST Failed !!!
ath5k: probe of 0000:04:01.0 failed with error -11
ath5k: phy1: POST Failed !!!
```

Any help would be appreciated..